# Upload photo to Tumblr API with nodejs and request module

Tags: node.js, request, tumblr, npm-request

So I want to upload an image to the Tumblr API with the npm request module.
Being familiar with the facebook and twitter API, those requests worked like this:

for Facebook:
- create a readstream: var media = fs.createReadStrem('imgpath');
- make a post request with access data and uri set and:

```
options.formData = {
  source: media,
  caption: "test"
};
```

for Twitter:
 - create readstream
 - upload image to twitter:

```
options.formData = {
  media: media
};
```

this works flawlessly.
But now with Tumblr, I need to encode the image as **"Array (URL-encoded binary contents)"** first.

So my question is. How do I encode it and bring it in the right format for the npm request module. To do this, I first need to load the image with **fs.readFileSync**, but is it possible to upload images to Tumblr as readStream like I did with FB and Twitter?

Here is one of the things I tried:

```
var img = fs.readFileSync('img');  
options.form = { 
  type: 'photo',
  data: [img.toString('binary')]
}
```

which gives me a 400: Error uploading photo.

I also looked into [tumblrwks](https://github.com/arkxu/tumblrwks), which works, but I really want to get this done with [request](https://github.com/request/request)

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are restricted to use request than you can convert data to hex using the following code

```
encodeToHex = require('./encode-image').encodeToHex;
var photo = fs.readFileSync('./test/img/P1010486.jpg');

options.form = { 
  type: 'photo',
  data: encodeToHex(photo),
}
```

encode-image is used by tumblrwks iteself

Comment: The encodeToHex function from encode-image basically does this:  
    var encodeToHex = function(buffer) {
      return "data:" + (buffer.toString('binary'));
    };  
which I also tried, but tumblr still responds with the same Error.

Comment: @instance if you see code for tumblrwks nodejs in /lib/tumblrwks.js file it is appending image file to oa object and to this object certain authentication parameters are added.